# Example Heavy Real Analysis book

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a real analysis text that is example heavy or at least *example-thorough*. I am studying for my exit exams that I have to take in a month and I need to prepare. I currently read *Elementary Real Analysis* by Thomson, Bruckner, and Bruckner. While this text contains tons of concepts from real analysis, this book lacks detailed examples. That is to say, Thomson et. al. will provide an example and say something like, "this can be demonstrated using elementary methods," but typically fails to thoroughly go through those examples.

Does anyone here know of any real analysis books are example-heavy or at the very least have examples that are broken down from start to finish? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of books, maybe look at the results of a google search for ["solutions" + "qualifying exams" + "real analysis"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solutions%22+%22qualifying+exams%22+%22real+analysis%22&filter=0).

Comment: Look, the point of real analysis is precisely to torment the student.

Comment: @copper.hat truer words have never been spoken

Comment: Personally I liked Marsden's "Real Analysis" and Kolmogorov & Fomin's of same name.

Comment: If you really do want torment, then Gelbaum & Olmsted's "Counterexamples in Analysis".

Comment: @copper.hat as long as they break the examples down, I’m cool with it

Comment: Probably not your book then...

Comment: Just so you know, even experts (not me) can find even simple variations of problems to be difficult. Real analysis is like mountain climbing.

Comment: @copper.hat I think that statement is generalizable to all of analysis. Have you seen complex?? Just do a couple of contour integrals using residue theory and you'll quickly see that it's actually the methods of analysis that are the tormenters, not necessarily $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Well, complex has its issues, but is much more complete than real analysis :-).

Comment: @copper.hat well I would say that both the real line and the complex plane are complete LOL, just take any Cauchy sequence